# DMZ server unable to connect through SQL Browser

Tags: sql-server

I have a Web server in my DMZ, I have a SQL Server 2008 R2 server inside the LAN, this database server has named instance with a NO dynamic port. I have set as firewall rules the connection from my DMZ server and the database server in the SQL Server instance port and the UDP port 1434 for SQL Browser.

I thought this will be enough to allow the connection between the two servers, however I created a UDL file in my DMZ server and tried to connect to the SQL server instance and it failed, but when I included the Instance port in the string, it worked.

Please can you help me, I want to be able to connect to the named instance without including the Instance port, instead use the SQL Browser as it would be for other serves inside the LAN.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have another SQL Server instance running on the server?

Answer (score 1):

Although what you described should work as configured, another option would be just create an alias for your named instance.